# Digits precision of the ".write" function?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, truncate

I want to store my data in a .txt file by using the "write" function in python.

The problem is that my values are around 9 digits after the point and the "write" function truncates after only 6.

For exemple if I want to write 0.000000604 I will get into the txt file 0.000000

I didn't see any option to change this precision...  Someone know how to deal with that?

Here is how I use it :

```
fres = open("results.dat","w")
fres.write("%f %f %f\n" % (abstime, np.mean(x), np.mean(y),0.00000005))
fres.close()
```

Comment: https://pyformat.info

Comment: "0.000000604" resulted in "0.000000"?  I'd expect  "0.000001".

Comment: The `write()` function simply writes whatever string you give it. The _string format_ step is what causes your loss of precision.

Comment: It should not be "The problem is that my values are around 9 digits after the point", but the number of _significant digits_.  Consider `%.9g`.